# Is watching match preview where they predict which team will win haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sports

Is it haram to watch match preview where they discuss which team ha supper edge in the match which team they think will win? I think most of the time they say the word could which I think shows that is a probability but sometimes they say a team will definitely but it's very rare, is this still haram?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think it would be Haram?

In Islam, everything is permitted unless explicitly stated or an ijtehad is reached by the Ulema on subjects that the Quran & Hadith are silent upon.

If the anchors are simply their predictions ***backed by analysis*** is it not wrong. It is like strategizing for a war or game. You analyze all permutations and combinations inorder to figure out the best way to win. Whether you win or out, is left to Allah.

However, using a cat, octopus, parrot or even a soothsayer to tell the result of the match without any research but to deceive people & earn money is prohibited.

I hope I was able to differentiate the nuances above for you.